# Proving a matrix is not nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries. Prove that no matrix $A^2 + A + I$ is nilpotent.

I tried to approach by contradiction and suppose that such an $A$ did exist so $(A^2 + A + I)^n = [0]$. I then need to figure $A^2 + A + I$, but the function $x^2 + x + 1$ doesn't factor over $\mathbb{R}$, and the factorization over $\mathbb{C}$ isn't very helpful. Is the fact that it doesn't factor over $\mathbb{R}$ enough?

Comment: This seems to be false as stated. For instance, the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&-1}
$$
satisfies $A^2 + A + I = 0$, and $0$ is nilpotent

Comment: This is false as written; if $A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{array} \right]$ you can check that $A^2 + A + I = 0$, which is nilpotent. Does "nilpotent" here mean "nilpotent and nonzero"?

Answer (score 3):

This statement is false. We find that the companion matrix associated with the polynomial $(x^2 + x + 1)^2 = x^4 + 2x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x + 1$ is given by
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&0&0&-1\\1&0&0&-2\\0&1&0&-3\\0&0&1&-2}.
$$
This matrix has real entries, but it satisfies $(A^2 + A + I)^2 = 0$. In fact, we find that $A^2 + A + I \neq 0$, which means that $A^2 + A + I$ is a non-zero nilpotent matrix.

---

For posterity: as discussed in the comments to this answer, you can get an answer in "real Jordan form", namely
$$
A = \pmatrix{C&I\\0 & C}, \quad C = \pmatrix{-1/2 & -\sqrt{3}/2\\\sqrt{3}/2& -1/2}. 
$$
We could also take
$$
C = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&-1},
$$
which is an interesting blend of approaches.

If you use another version of the real Jordan form, you might instead end up with the example
$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
-1/2 & 1 & -\sqrt{3}/2 & 0\\
0 & -1/2 & 0 & -\sqrt{3}/2\\
\hline
\sqrt{3}/2 & 0 & -1/2 & 1\\
0 & \sqrt{3}/2 & 0 & -1/2
\end{array}\right].
$$

Comment: Nice! I had just constructed a $4 \times 4$ example using a generalized Jordan block but this works and is a bit easier.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That works too. Another idea that occurred to me was to build a complex example and use the standard representation of $\Bbb C^2$ in $M_2(\Bbb R)$ to replace the blocks and get a $4 \times 4$ example, but I guess that really amounts to the same thing as using the "real Jordan form", which I guess is what you mean by a generalized Jordan block.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera You're right, thanks for the correction