# Is this method for constructing nilpotent matrices effective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, ring-theory, nilpotence

I am currently in the process of familiarizing myself with linear algebra, so there may be inaccuracies in my question.

The method of constructing nilpotent matrices is as follows:

1. Randomly pick a monic polynomial $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}\cdot x^{n-1}+...+a_0$;
2. Find the companion matrix $C$ associated with the polynomial $g(x)=f(x)^k$;
3. Let the nilpotent matrix $B=f(C)$.

The above inspiration is derived from the answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922906/proving-a-matrix-is-not-nilpotent). I am uncertain whether taking the companion matrix $C$ as the input of $f(x)$ would result in $B^k=0$, due to some related thoerems that I have not yet come across.

Comment: It looks like your polynomials are all linear.  You should be able to rewrite this as a product of two matrices, one of coefficients and the other of the $z$s.  Not sure if this helps solve the problem though since the matrices aren’t square.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist I changed the description of my question.

Comment: @MichaelBurr  I changed the description of my question.

Comment: @mingalex You should undo the last edit so the question is visible without viewing the history. The point of this website is to archive good questions and answers, not to answer questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your matrix $\ B\ $ will always be nilpotent.  This follows from the fact that the companion matrix $\ C\ $ of a polynomial $\ g(x)\ $ must satisfy
the equation $\ g(C)=0\ .$ In fact $\ g(x)\ $ is its characteristic polynomial, as has been proved in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76469/characteristic-polynomial-of-companion-matrix/76477#76477), and the fact that $\ g(C)=0\ $ then follows from the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem). Thus, if $\ g(x)= f(x)^k\ $ where $\ k\ge2\ $, then
\begin{align}
0&=g(C)\\
&=(f(C))^k\ .
\end{align}
Therefore $\ B=f(C)\ $ is nilpotent.  It's also trivially nilpotent when $\ k=1\ ,$ because $\ B\ $ must be the zero matrix in that case, which is normally of no interest.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! However, I cannot find the related thoerems or lemmas to demonstrate the fact you mentioned that *"the companion matrix  $C$ 
 of a polynomial  $g(x)$ must satisfy the equation  $g(C)=0$"*. Could you further explain the fact?

Comment: @ming alex I've added a link to a proof that a polynomial  $\ g\ $ is the characteristic polynomial of its companion matrix $\ C\ $, and noted that the identity $\ g(C)=0\ $ then follows from the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: I have verified the correctness of this method though the Mathematica software. Thank you!